# Introduction on Controller for the view part

Tags: yii, yii-components

Yii has its own controls for its View part, I try to look for a complete tutorial that introduce those controls but fail. What I found is this is partial set of introduction:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/143/htmloptions-explained-for-various-controls/

Can anyone point me to a good reference?

Comment: I think all you need is in the documentation, for example if you take a dropdonwList then you'll know all the possibilities here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail . For each CHtml controls you'll find its specific options in the documentation!

Comment: @darkheir  I am actually looking for tutorial that provides more friendly guide to the html controller. But what you provide is indeed very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You should start with http://www.larryullman.com/2009/11/15/basic-controller-edits-in-yii/
This will give you an idea about how controllers work in Yii and how to edit them according to your need.
Basically Yii has "action" functions for all the views. Lets just say if you want to render register page for a user, you'll have to create "actionRegister" in userscontroller and then render register view from it.
You could also use http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller.
Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, actually I have read quite some of this, I am just interest on the tutorial that help us hands on for making use of yii html controller.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Yii is somewhat limited as you have found out, but I have found that most of my questions are already answered here if I serch for specific issues that I am having.